# How do i list all the servers in a WAS7 Profile on the commandline?

Tags: command-line, websphere, websphere-7

I want to use wasadmin or some other command to list out all the servers in a profile, but looking through the IBMknowledge center its not so straight forward to find.

Can anybody tell what command can be used? I am on a windows 7 system.

Comment: It is not recommended to use multiple servers in the same profile. Do you have a business requirement for this?

Comment: A good starting place for help in many wsadmin commands is using the [wsadminlib](https://github.com/wsadminlib/wsadminlib).

Answer (score 4):

You can use [serverStatus](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/ae/rxml_serverstatus.html?lang=en) command line tool. It will list all the servers in the profile, with their current status (stopped/started), like below:

```
C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85\profiles\AppSrv1\bin>serverStatus.bat -all
ADMU0116I: Tool information is being logged in file
           C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85\profiles\AppSrv1\logs\serverStatus.log
ADMU0128I: Starting tool with the AppSrv1 profile
ADMU0503I: Retrieving server status for all servers
ADMU0505I: Servers found in configuration:
ADMU0506I: Server name: server1
ADMU0509I: The Application Server "server1" cannot be reached. It appears to be
           stopped.
```